# Script that fixes YML SIDs to be simplified for production

Tags: python, beginner, yaml

I work with YML files that include SIDs and the following structure:

```
    title:
  "2": "content a" # key: comment 
  "3": "content b" # key: comment 
  "4": "content c" # key: comment 
  "5": "content d" # key: comment 
  "6": "content e" # key: comment
```

Usually, I have to remove some strings (note I never remove the number 1 or 2) so my new file looks like this:

```
    title:
  "2": "content a" # key: comment 
  "3": "content b" # key: comment 
  "5": "content d" # key: comment 
  "6": "content e" # key: comment
```

I need to rearrange the SIDs in order to have a sequence without any gap (in this case 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) independently on the content. For that reason I have written the following script. It works properly but I need to bring it into production so I need your help to **reduce its complexity, make it clear and simpler or any advice you may have for a beginner** (in both, Python and Stack Exchange).

```
import re, os

file=input ('YML file name: ')

#read the file and store its content as a list
os.chdir('/home/balaclava/Desktop/Scripts/YML fixer/')
rdfile= open(file)
cont=rdfile.readlines()
rdfile.close()

#list to store the reviewed strings
newfile=[]
newfile.append(cont[0]+cont[1])

#Get the second string SID as reference
numRegex = re.compile(r'\d+')
act=numRegex.search(cont[1])
global refnum
refnum=int(act.group())

#Loop for each string (-2 due to the two first string are excluded)
for i in range(len(cont)-2):              
    act=numRegex.search(str(cont[i+2])) 
    temp=int(act.group()) 
#If the SID is correct, add item to newlist, else, fix it and add the item to the list.              
    if temp == (refnum+1):              
        newfile.append(cont[i+2])
    else:
        temp= (refnum+1)       
        change=numRegex.sub(str(temp), cont[i+2])
        newfile.append(change)    
    refnum += 1

#overwrite the file with the newlist content
with open (file,'w') as finalfile:
    finalfile.write(''.join(newfile))
    finalfile.close()
```

Comment: Instead of attacking this with regexes, why not just do a `yaml.load` to bring it in, and modify it using regular python operations on the resulting data structure? It would be clear, and there would be no risk of corrupting the format.

Comment: @AustinHastings, yaml.load would not keep the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use rumael.yaml, it can preserve comments. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255885/save-dump-a-yaml-file-with-comments-in-pyyaml#27103244

Moreover, you want to be a better python developer (or maybe pythonist?) I can give you some tips:

**Content duplication**
You are storing the file content inside `cont` and after closing the file you are duplicating that info in a new variable `newfile` I think that is an unnecessary process in this situation. You could store all the data in `cont` and just modify the lines needed. You can replace the entire if-else by:

```
    if temp != (refnum+1):              
        temp= (refnum+1)       
        change=numRegex.sub(str(temp), cont[i])
        cont[i] = change
```

**For loop's range**
Change your range call in the for loop to `range(2, len(cont)):`
Now inside the loop you can access the current line with simply `cont[i]` it's more readable and efficient.

As with `i`'s range you are accessing refnum always with a +1. By initializing it as `refnum=int(act.group()) +1` your code saves that operations inside the loop. Another thing that you can do is do the +=1 increment at the beginning of the loop.

**File management**
You don't need to manually close files when using `with` statement you can remove `finalfile.close()`. Another thing, you are using `with` in the when writing but not when reading, think about always use the same method.

More things can be changed but I think that's enough for now.